# Nothing happens when executing a python shebang script in /usr/local/bin/

Tags: python, executable, shebang

**Nothing happens when executing a python shebang script in /usr/local/bin/**

Hopefully someone can help me. So i made a simple python program called *test* for testing out shebang scripts(I have used chmod to make it executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "hello"
```

after i copied it to /usr/local/bin/ i tried to call it by typing in 
my shell:`test`
but nothing happened...
(There were no errors)

Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is actually a shell builtin:

```
$ type test
test is a shell builtin
```

Rename your script to something else or run it directly by executing `/usr/local/bin/test`.

Comment: yes. In fact, if you run it with `./test` it works :)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, to compensate for the silly downvote you got

Answer (score 1):

Blender is right: 'test' is an unfortunate name choice for your file.  There is already a shell builtin function called 'test'.  It would be the same if you tried to make a python script called 'ls'.  The reason it works when executing './test' is due to the fact that './' tells the shell to make the current directory first in the executable path.  If you rename your python script to 'bangtest' and make sure it has executable permissions (chmod +x bangtest), it will work in the manner you desire.